# Find limit of $\frac{2x+7}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}$ (check my steps please..)

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification

> Compute the limit $$\lim_{x\to-\infty}{\frac{2x+7}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}}$$

Here are my steps: 
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x+7}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{2x+7}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}\cdot\frac{-1/x}{-1/x}=\frac{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty}-2-\frac{7}{x}}{\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2x-1}{x^2}}}=\frac{-2}{1}=-2$$
But I am not confident about $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to-\infty}{\sqrt\frac{x^2+2x-1}{x^2}}$. I just suppose that $x$ can be 'large enough' to ignore $+2x-1$.

Comment: All of your steps are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. Note that\begin{align}\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{\frac{x^2+2x-1}{x^2}}&=\sqrt{\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(1+\frac2x-\frac1{x^2}\right)}\\&=\sqrt{1}\\&=1.\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! =)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid confution the best way when we deal with limit $\to -\infty $ is to change variable and set $x=-y$ with $y\to +\infty$ then

$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}{\frac{2x+7}{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}}}=\lim_{y\to+\infty}{\frac{-2y+7}{\sqrt{y^2-2y-1}}}=\lim_{y\to+\infty}{\frac{y}{y}\frac{-2+7/y}{\sqrt{1-2/y-1/y^2}}}=-2$$

Comment: @ethanlevy97 you are welcome, it's often a good trick when limits are taken not at $0$ or $+\infty$.